# How to maximize the result of multiplying lengths of the two strings without common characters

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

Given a list of words, find two strings `S` and `T` such that:

1. `S` and `T` have no common character
2. `S.length() * T.length()` is maximized

My approach is, building bitmap for each string first and tries to find the maximum multiply. Can you give me a better algorithm with time complexity less then O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

```cpp
public class biggest_multiply {
    int biggest(String[] array){
        if(array==null||array.length<=1)
            return 0;
        class bitMap{
            int bit;
            String s;
        }
        bitMap[] bm=new bitMap[array.length];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            bm[i]=new bitMap();
            for(int j=0;j<array[i].length();j++)
                bm[i].bit=bm[i].bit|(1<<(array[i].charAt(j)-'a'));
            bm[i].s=array[i];
        }
        int maximum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
                if((bm[i].bit&bm[j].bit)==0)
                    maximum=Math.max(maximum, bm[i].s.length()*bm[j].s.length());
        }
        return maximum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new biggest_multiply().biggest(new String[]{"aa","aabb","bb","cc"}));
    }
}
```

Comment: At least make an attempt at your own homework problem.

Comment: this is not a homework..I saw it online and thought it is an interesting problem.
I can only think of making hashset or bitmap for each string's characters and compare one by one. However, finding the maximized multiply result cost O(n^2)...

Comment: This is a tough one.  The element distinctness problem tells us that we can't determine if two words have no common character in better than O(m lg m) time (assuming average word length is m).  Maybe there's a better algorithm for the amortized case, but I don't know of any.  We can use a hash table to "break" this boundary for O(m) time, but that assumes a constant time hash function, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the words by word.length() descending, so short circuit can be done to speed up. But still O(n^2).

```
if (bm[i].s.length() * bm[j].s.length() <= max)
    break;

if ((bm[i].bit & bm[j].bit)==0) {
    maximum=Math.max(maximum, bm[i].s.length()*bm[j].s.length());
    break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A straight forward solution is to try every possible match of words in S & T. The runtime would be O(n*m), where n is the number of words and m is the size of a word.

A better way is to pre-compute the character map in each word and the size before our iteration. The runtime would reduce to O(n).

Comment: Wouldn't trying every possible match of words be O(n^2 m^2)?  Iterating over all of the words once would be O(nm).  Having a character map for each word would then reduce it to O(n^2 m).  This solution seems to be the same as the one the user suggested in his or her comment above.